# Can't remove package sucessfully with "conda remove"

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I installed with a downloaded ".tar.bz2" file, but it couldn't work. So I used `conda install basemap` trying to cover the wrong one, this sentence carried out successfully, but the version of basemap was still wrong. I tried to use `conda remove basemap`, it ran for hours but no result.

How can I remove it successfully?
Thanks for any kind help.